# Loading pdf file from AWS s3 into iframe does not work in IE 11

Tags: html, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I have ASP.NET Core web application. The view is using `iframe` to load PDF file from amazon s3.

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:100vh" src="https://xxxx.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/a_01_03_44_35_5745663485955446.pdf"></iframe>
```

The above code was working fine until recently.

Now iframe does not show any pdf. When i check network using F12 it shows `Protocol` and `Result/Description` as `Pending`

[image]

<strike>if copy the URL and paste it into IE 11 directly then browser shows the file.</strike>

The above behavior is happening in IE 11 and IE Edge, as usual chrome works fine.

I am not sure if recent windows update has got anything to do with this.

**Update 1**
I take it back, I cannot open S3 url in IE 11 or IE Edge directly either.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. Why don't you load the PDF with HttpClient and serve it through a controller. Could also have the benefit that you can cache it if this is frequently requested. Or better use the AWS SDK.

Comment: that will unnecessarily increase HTTP traffic and also bandwidth from our web server to client

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since the begining of 2017/08. The difference is I cannot open the url directly on IE11 and Edge eigther. The F12 network tab also shows both Protocal and Result/Description as Pending. No problem on Chrome, firefox and safari.

Several PCs in our company started having this problem from the same time.

Here is a [sample url](https://my-first-s3-bucket-25c36bc6-0666-4533-9215-83487f25bd1e.s3.amazonaws.com/uaitnxxainttest/No10005_20161101095819.pdf)

(please open this by IE11 on Windows10).

Comment: You are correct, it does not work in IE11 or Edge either even if i put url directly in the browser address bar.. ( i have updated my post)

Comment: I found I can open the pdfs now both in IE11 and Edge at present. I didn't change any settings on IIS nor on AWS. Perhaps MS or AWS made some changes.

Comment: i still cannot open your sample link in IE 11 or edge

Comment: I am using Japanese version of Windows 10 pro, maybe there is time lag of english version ? I confirmed with our staffs that they can view the pdfs in IE11, Edge and in the iframe too. Wish you good luck too.